# DEDUCT/ADD VALUES TO DB TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

i have a two table I want to update the quantity of the other table.

item table

```
id  |   item_name               |   qty
1       plantronics headset         50
```

issue table

```
id  |   user                    |   issued_qty
1       John Yap                |   10
```

Whenever I tried to issue 10 pieces of headset to John, the quantity of the item table will become 40 that is normal, however If there are some changes to the items to be issued let say for example, John just needs 5 headset, I will edit the issued_qty to 5.the item table quantity will become 35 instead of 45.

```
UPDATE item SET qty = qty - $quantityToIssue WHERE item_serial = '$serial'";
```

Comment: Do not update quantity of item table instead subtract issue table quantity from item table quantity on while displaying available quantity

Comment: While modifying the quantity from 10 to 5, that time update the item table qty as "qty = qty+5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the values of `item` table accordingly, you will have to consider the previous and current values of `issued_qty`.

It can work this way :

`qty = qty + previous_issued_qty - current_issued_qty`